# Laravel - npm run watch does not work on Lara 7, Node: v10.15.0 and NPM: v6.5.0

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I have an issue with Laravel and Vue. When I try to compile everything with npm run watch I get these (it suddenly stopped working):

```
Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.

Running: yarn add vue-template-compiler --dev --production=false
/bin/sh: yarn: command not found
/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:244
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: Command failed: yarn add vue-template-compiler --dev --production=false
/bin/sh: yarn: command not found

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:653:13)
    at Dependencies.execute (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dependencies.js:52:22)
    at dependencies.reject.tap.dependencies (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dependencies.js:30:22)
    at Array.value (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:24:13)
    at Dependencies.install (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dependencies.js:29:14)
    at Function.dependencies (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Assert.js:77:40)
    at concat.filter.tap.dependencies (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:130:24)
    at Array.value (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/helpers.js:24:13)
    at ComponentFactory.installDependencies (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:129:14)
    at Mix.listen (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:54:44)
    at events.(anonymous function).forEach.handler (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:47)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Dispatcher.fire (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Dispatcher.js:34:28)
    at Mix.dispatch (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:119:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:19:5)
    at Module._compile (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:133:13)
    at requireConfig (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:135:6)
    at /Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:142:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:140:15)
    at yargs.parse (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:241:39)
    at Object.parse (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:219:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:538:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kosingas/.npm/_logs/2018-12-31T13_48_22_168Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kosingas/.npm/_logs/2018-12-31T13_48_22_209Z-debug.log
Borivojes-MacBook-Pro:lvue kosingas$
```

I am not sure what to do. Have been googling for quote some time, downgraded Node from 11 to stable LTS version 10 and nothing.

[Click here to see the screenshot of the errors that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plHEK.png)

This is what I see when I open the error log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'watch' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v10.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39$
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: /Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue
10 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development -- --watch' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /Applications/MAMP_2018-03-15_05-39-43/htdocs/sandbox/lvue
16 verbose Darwin 18.0.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v10.15.0
```

Comment: Do you have Yarn installed on your system?
Also which operating system are you using?
Did you run `Yarn install` before running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'`vue-template-compiler`' is missing on your packag.json, do :

```
rm -R node_modules 
npm install 
npm install -g yarnpkg
npm install --save vue-template-compiler
npm run dev
```

Comment: Hi Leorent. Thank you for your help. That did help to some extent. 

But now I'm getting these (when I run npm run dev):

ERROR in ./resources/js/App.vue
Module build failed: Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.17
- vue-template-compiler@2.5.21

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

Comment: remove `node_modules` file and try to reinstall it again. It should work I have faced this version missmatch many times usually it gets resolved with a rm node_modules and a fresh npm install

Comment: Hm that did not help. I am using Vue CLI 3. Should I be using previous version?

Comment: @BoraManasijevic hmm redo the steps above except `npm install vue-template-compiler --save-dev`  and see if that works

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do the trick. Same problem:

ERROR in ./resources/js/App.vue
Module build failed: Error: 

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.17
- vue-template-compiler@2.5.21

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

Comment: I started with fresh Laravel installation. And then I installed yarn, since it's newer than yarnpkg and npm run watch works now.

Leorent, thank you for your help and effort, you've guided me in the right way. Also you were right, I was missing vue-template-compiler dependency in my previous package.json of previous laravel installation.

I will mark your answer as the right one, since you were correct. Thanks once again.

Cheers, and Happy New Year! :)

Comment: Half a year later and a helpful answer, solved the issue :)